# Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, visual-web-developer-2010

Does Visual Web Developer 2010 Express edition have ASP.NET MVC 2 based web site development facility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Visual Web Developer 2010 Express [has MVC2 support out of the box](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/12/visual-web-developer-2010-express-has-arrived.aspx). You can also develop MVC3 applications in it if you install [MVC3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491).